# Flutter DateTimeField

Tags: flutter, showtimepicker

Flutter Material3 showTimePicker issues with time selector container size. Does anyone know how to resize the container to get full-text size? Overriding the theme does the trick overriding material3 theme. But I need the timepicker to use localization since without one it won't be able to use the current AppLocalization and default to another language.

```
 onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) async {
                  final time = await showTimePicker(
                    builder: (context, child) {
                      // return Theme(
                      //     data: ThemeData.light(),
                      //     child: Container(
                      //       child: child));
                      return Localizations.override(
                        context: context,
                        locale: _locale,
                        child: child,
                      );
                    },
                    // builder: (context, child) {
                    //   return Column(
                    //     children: <Widget>[
                    //       Padding(
                    //         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                    //         child: Container(
                    //           // height: screenHeight / 1.1,
                    //           child: child,
                    //         ),
                    //       ),
                    //     ],
                    //   );
                    // },
                    context: context,
                    initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(
                        currentValue ?? DateTime.now()),
                  );
```

[image]